# Object is possibly 'undefined' using ES6 Map.get() right after Map.set()

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Running the following snipped I'm getting a `Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)` error.

```js
const myMap = new Map<string, number>();

myMap.set('test', 1);

// Object is possibly 'undefined'.
myMap.get('test') / 2;
```

I'm using TypeScript 4.5.4 (also checked on  4.4.4)

If this is intended, could someone explain how the example above could possibly still be undefined?

Comment: This is not reproducible as written; please [edit] this into a [mre] by (for example) changing your `myMap` initializer to `new Map<string, number>();`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is somewhat of a design limitation of TypeScript; the compiler can't keep track of the state of the `Map` that way.  There's a (fairly old) feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#9619](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9619) to support [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) for `Map` methods.

It can't be done without changing the language, though.  Currently [`Map<K, V>` is declared](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c71ff4dcdf60c373ea0ccca56b112311470c38b0/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) as an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces).  The `set()` method has a return type of `this` (because calling `set()` returns the same `Map` instance).  And the `get()` method has a return type of `V | undefined`.

But there's not really a way to say that `set()` *mutates the state* of the instance so that `get()` with the "right" keys will return just `V` instead of `V | undefined`.  In some sense you want calling `myMap.set("test", 1)` to change the type of `myMap` from `Map<string, number>` (which doesn't know what keys have actual values) to something like `Map<string, number> & {get("test"): number}`.  Presumably you'd want `myMap.delete("test")` to change the type to `Map<string, number> & {get("test"): undefined}`.  But TypeScript doesn't let you represent arbitrary type mutations like this.  There are [assertion methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) but there are lots of caveats, the biggest of which is that they only strictly *narrow* a type, and if the compiler doesn't see the behavior as narrowing it won't work.

So right now it's basically a limitation.  That doesn't mean that `myMap.get('test')` can actually be `undefined`, just that the compiler doesn't know this.

---

Rather than wait for some possible future version of TypeScript to support this use case, you might want to work around it or refactor.  The easiest workaround is to just accept that you're cleverer than the compiler and use a [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to tell it that a value cannot be `null` or `undefined`:

```
const myMap = new Map<string, number>();
myMap.set("test", 1);
myMap.get("test")! / 2; // <-- no error
```

If you really need the compiler to keep track of such things, then you can refactor to use [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining); instead of having a single object named `myMap` whose state is different every time you call `set()`, you use multiple objects, each of which has a single constant state... when you call `set()` you get a new object.  It could look like this:

```
const init = new MyMap();
//const init: MyMap<{}> 

const afterSet = init.set("test", 1); 
//const afterSet: MyMap<Record<"test", number>>

const val = afterSet.get("test") / 2;
```

Or like this:

```
const m = new MyMap().set("test", 1).set("foo", "abc").set("baz", false);
m.get("foo").toUpperCase();
m.get("test").toFixed();
m.get("blah") // error! not a valid key
```

Here's one possible implementation (only dealing with `get()` and `set()` but you could implement other methods too):

```
interface MyMap<T extends object = {}> {
  set<K extends keyof T>(k: K, v: T[K]): this;
  set<K extends string, V>(k: Exclude<K, keyof T>, v: V): MyMap<T & Record<K, V>>;
  get<K extends string>(k: K): K extends keyof T ? T[K] : undefined;
}
const MyMap = Map as new () => MyMap;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgMIAWIAlsHoUUvQC4QBOAZuUgLIBPPiBgAeACpIIAD3bAAJlCQB7AEYArCPFZIAvHgC+APkbNmUCK1EBpKbIgKlAawgDlXJOKMAKJwC4kawAaJAA3APEAbWsAXQBKANYqWigAbiYzCytbGTlFJChWDnoAcxCANR9-JABRaXgMAFd5CBsQlzcPLxDwpHKE-iERCSQAMiQAJS1lDnk2vqMjdLMiEssbOzznV3dPKoDrAajY5eYDDKR4ZWBCweEYPX4RJBAlYAgAdyRvOL0TQXupyIVxuOnotB0+neXwBIh+QKQAHpESDbuDWAFYWJcMYLqidCAuOwOABlSyPdEAOiy3gAROxCrSQgBGOII5H4l5EzhkjF3YZTK6zUT06CsJnERpgVScRZ4663UKYR6E4m8ylrVh0hni36IpAAJnS8tBSDAj2h-JgP2plm1YolrNtWtpXGUygltJAqngtLizrpqhAWAlPAwFjZFzAGrtrvdfsprGUAFUYDBOBRXhB4VGYy6dQmkwAxWjSCDyHNmaOawMYEBUP1I-WcDgzACExGUBLCmFo8iQHXwTHOTBI0DgiCQAEEoBYODoCGZOWAhg8oZ8nmJCsVgGVJdLZZXmCv7gHRYyWZGq6u8-bGXEO-qjUOiCODEA)

Comment: In my project, we don't allow the 'Non-null assertion operator' for other good reasons. Another option is to use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator.


const myMap = new Map<string, Array>();
myMap.set("test", []);
myMap.get("test")?.push('Foo')

Answer (score 8):

Typescript doesn't keep track of the `.set` `.get` references, and the default signature of `.get` is `T | undefined`, so you can either:

- assert `myMap.get('test')!` (be very careful doing this as code in between the `.set` and `.get` could change/delete that item)
- handle the possibility of the item being undefined and act accordingly

```js
const myMap = new Map<string, number>();

myMap.set('test', 1);

// Object is possibly 'undefined'.
const item = myMap.get('test');
if (item !== undefined) {
  item / 2;
} else {
  throw new Error('Item is undefined');
}
```